# Late 1960's Comic Book with H shaped space ship

Tags: story-identification, comics, spaceship

In a period approximately from 1967 - 1971 I remember reading a space adventure comic book with an unusually shaped spaceship with a crew of, I think, scientists-explorers. I cannot remember the details such as title or characters, except that I don't remember them being superhero types. But I remember being enthralled with their adventures. However the space ship left an image I still remember. It was, head on, H shaped with the legs of the H tilting inward at the bottom. The cross bar of the H had a dome on it and was the central area of action on board. If I remember correctly as I write this the dome had a large telescope mounted in it. The space ship was fairly large. It didn't have obvious things typical of the time like rocket shapes or tubes for propulsion.

I searched for comic book images and for 1960s comic book space ships, I've searched for space ships shaped as an H (there must be some very good AI judging from the images that came back in a Google search), but none matching what I am looking for.

I have tried to create a rough image of what I remember. 
[image: H Shaped Space Ship]

Comment: The answer already proposed seems like a perfect match. However, I do seem to recall at least one other H-shaped spaceship of some note: Sanctuary II, Thanos' spaceship, first seen in the 1970's (though a bit later than 1971, I believe).

Comment: @RDFozz: I don't think it had that telescope thingie in the middle though

Comment: I praise both your memory and your "drawing" skills, that's pretty impressive.

Comment: +1 for drawing your replica in MS PowerPoint, it's a relief to know I'm not the only one who uses it as an all-purpose drawing tool.

Comment: Thank you. My first attempt at drawing it was pen and I was going to scan it, but it was messy. My second attempt was using Paint, but it was too childish. (Although it did have the clear domes on top of the legs.)  I fell back on what I know. :-)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I remember that one! [*Space Family Robinson*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Family_Robinson)!

Here you go:

[image]

Comment: Space Family Robinson was the first thought I had when I read the question.

Comment: This raised issues with "Lost in Space", where the space-family was also named Robinson. It was being broadcast from 1965-68 (similar timeframe), and eventually a license was obtained.

Comment: ... which starred **June** Lockhart.

Comment: @theprogrammer which should be cleared up quickly by reading the linked wiki article

Comment: Space Family Robinson was created by Ib Melchior as a pitch for a TV series, but it was rejected by Irwin Allen - who shortly after pitched the essentially identical idea for Lost in Space. Melchior then reworked his idea into the Gold Key comic.

Comment: Thank you. This must be it! I was going to edit my response to include details like the crossbar wasn't perfectly rectangular and it positioned higher in the legs than right across them middle (i.e., I drew it that way on purpose), and that I remembered their using some type of shuttle. In my first couple drawing attempts I included the domes at the of the legs as that detail came to me while drawing - but I wasn't sure so in the final I left them out because A) I was uncertain, and B) I couldn't do it. But glad to see it in this image because is further confirmation you've helped me.

Comment: One reason I remembered this was because I didn't see the comic series to the end and it was left unresolved in my memory, and I wondered what happened, but given the story line I can now see that is how it was. Was it ever resolved or are they still Lost in Space?